# Only show certain <div> if there's a certain element on the page

Tags: javascript, html, css, zendesk

I'm trying to get the company I'm at a Help Centre set up, using Zendesk.

I've managed to implement a sidenav, but I'm struggling to make it show different anchor links depending on the category of the Help Centre the user is on. Zendesk only allows you to edit the HTML of the category page template, and I'm unable to dynamically load in the links.

Can anyone please advise on how to show `DIV_1`, only if the page contains `<li title="Using ProductName">`? I've searched but can't seem to find anything relevant.

From there I'll do the same for the other sections in the same way (e.g. only show `DIV_2` if the page contains `<li title="Developer Portal"`.

For reference, I have access to the category's HTML template, the CSS and JS.

Thanks in advance!

```html
<div class="container">
  <nav class="sub-nav">
    <ol class="breadcrumbs">
  
    <li title="Help Centre">
      
        <a href="/hc/en-us?preview%5Btheme_id%5D=209312965&amp;preview_as_role=manager&amp;use_theme_settings=false">Help Centre</a>
      
    </li>
  
    <li title="Using ProductName">
      
        Using ProductName
      
    </li>
  
</ol>
```

```html
    
    <div id="DIV_1">
    <ul id="UL_2">
        <li id="LI_1">
            <a href="#uniqueID0" id="A_1">Admin and Settings</a>
        </li>
    <li id="LI_1">
            <a href="#uniqueID1" id="A_1">Getting Started</a>
        </li>
        <li id="LI_1">
            <a href="#uniqueID2" id="A_1">Content Types and Sources</a>
        </li>
    <li id="LI_1">
            <a href="#uniqueID3" id="A_1">Content Management</a>
        </li>
     <li id="LI_1">
            <a href="#uniqueID4" id="A_1">Content Publishing</a>
        </li>
        <li id="LI_1">
            <a href="#uniqueID5" id="A_1">Apps</a>
        </li>
    <li id="LI_1">
            <a href="#uniqueID6" id="A_1">Analytics</a>
        </li>
        <li id="LI_1">
            <a href="#uniqueID7" id="A_1">Troubleshooting</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built-in DOM query methods to accomplish this. In this case, you'd want to combine an `if` condition with the query, something like so:

```
if (document.querySelector('li[title="Using ProductName"]')) {
    // make #DIV_1 visible however you please here
    document.querySelector('#DIV_1').display = 'block';
}
```

If the `li` with the title `Using ProductName` does not exist, `#DIV_1` will stay invisible; if it does, it will be shown.

Comment: Thank you! I've tried this out, and unless I'm putting it in my JS tab wrong, [I don't think it works...](http://i.imgur.com/I2G3ArJ.png) (See image)

Comment: Perfect thank you, needed to be

`if (document.querySelector('li[title="Using ProductName"]')) {
    // make #DIV_1 visible however you please here
    document.querySelector('#DIV_1').style.display = 'block';
}`

Answer (score 0):

You can do a quick `for` loop check:

```
var items = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  if (items[i].title == titleToCheckFor) { showElement(); }
}
```

You can fill in `titleToCheckFor` with the title you're looking for ("Using _____") and the `showElement` function would display the `div`, or you could just show the `div` right in the loop.

Comment: Using  `for` to show and hide elements, is not reliability

Comment: @jamesjara please explain... what's unreliable about a `for` loop?

Answer (score 0):

Using DOM query method querySelector you can search the target element, by default we set all div's hidden, and then we show only the required.

```
<style>
   .module {
      display:none;
   }
</style>
<script>
   // by default we show MODULE A else show module B
   var module = "DIV_1"; 
   if (document.querySelector('li[title="Developer Portal"]')) { 
      module = "DIV_2"; 
   }
   // we show the respective DIV
   document.querySelector('.' + module).display = 'block'; 
</script>

<div class="module DIV_1" id="DIV_1">
 ...  
</div>  
<div class="module DIV_2" id="DIV_2">
....
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this via CSS classes.

**SOLUTION 1:**

This being the sample HTML:

```
<div id="Div_1" class="menu-div using-productname">
</div>
<div id="Div_2" class="menu-div help-centre">
</div>
<div id="Div_3" class="menu-div other-tab">
</div>
```

Now you should setup your css like:

```
.menu-div {
   display: none;
}
```

So all menu divs are hidden by default when the page loads

Now when you move to some tab suppose "Using ProductName", all you need to do is

```
var title = "Using ProductName"; //Get the title
var className = title.split(" ").join("-").toLowerCase(); //Convert it to the correct class which matches with your Divs in the menu
document.querySelector(".menu-div").style.display = "none";  //Set all menu divs to hidden
document.querySelector("." + className).style.display = "block";  //Show the desired menu div
```

**SOLUTION 2:**

This being the sample HTML:

```
<div class="parent-div">
<div id="Div_1" class="menu-div">
</div>
<div id="Div_2" class="menu-div">
</div>
<div id="Div_3" class="menu-div">
</div>
```

Now you should setup your css like:

```
.parent-div .menu-div {
   display: none;
}
.parent-div.using-productname #Div_1 {
   display: block;
}
.parent-div.help-centre #Div_2 {
   display: block;
}
.parent-div.other-tab #Div_3 {
   display: block;
}
```

Now when you move to some tab suppose "Using ProductName", all you need to do is

```
var title = "Using ProductName"; //Get the title
var className = title.split(" ").join("-").toLowerCase(); //Convert it to the correct class which you will add to the parent
document.querySelector(".parent-div").className = "parent-div " + className;   //Set the parent div class to the className - the css will take care of the rest!
```

NOTE - Also you should use different ids on your different LIs and A tags.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery in Zendesk Help Centers so

```
var test =  $('.breadcrumbs').children(':contains(amy)')
if(test.length > 0) {
   do something here like 
   $('#LI_1').hide();
}
```

It's kind of simple brute force, but it works.